# Return the whole dataframe in filtering a dataframe (Python / Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a function that returns a new filtered dataframe based on two different IDs. It works very well if the user gives as parameters both IDs. But I also want to be able to filter this very dataframe using only one ID. What default value can I assign to my arguments to force one (or both) of the comparison inside the df.loc[] to return the entire dataframe if a user doesn't specify a value?

I tried using values like (not None) but that didn't do the trick. I also tried to set the default parameter as df.ID_1, and that works because (df.ID_1 == df.ID_1) = True (makes sense right?). But in my real script my dataframe is created after you call the function, so I can't do that.

I know I can use a series of "if/else" to detect wether a user has entered a value or not and then write a new filter .loc for each case. But my real dataframe is huge and has several dozens of columns IDs, so the code would be very long and dirty to write.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1': [11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14],
                   'ID_2': [123, 124, 124, 124, 125, 125],
                   'Value': ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F']})

def return_a_new_filtered_df(ID_1=(not None),ID_2=(not None)):

     """return a new filtered dataframe

    Parameters:
    ID_1 (int): First ID
    ID_2 (int): Second ID

    Returns: a new pd dataframe

   """
    new_df = df.loc[(df.ID_1 == ID_1) & (df.ID_2 == ID_2)]
    return new_df

return_a_new_filtered_df(12,14) # -> Works like a charm

return_a_new_filtered_df(12) ### -> DOESN'T WORK !
```

With the last line, I expect the dataframe to be filtered with only the first ID. But it returns an empty dataframe and I totally understand why. So my question is :

With which value can I replace my default value ("not None") by a value that will make the other comparison return True and thus return the entire dataframe?

If you think about it it's a philosophical question about Python and Pandas. Is there a value that can makes a comparison returns True everytime? Can we filter on nothing so the filter doesn't filter when we don't need to?

Comment: excecute `print((not None))`. It will be True

Comment: And `df.ID_2 == ID_2` will never be `True`...

Comment: Thx, but that doesn't work because if df.loc[df.ID_1 == True] doesn't return anything as it contains integer and not boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def return_a_new_filtered_df(ID_1=None, ID_2=None):

    """return a new filtered dataframe

    Parameters:
    ID_1 (int): First ID
    ID_2 (int): Second ID

    Returns: a new pd dataframe

    """
    if ID_1 and ID_2:
        new_df = df.loc[(df.ID_1 == ID_1) & (df.ID_2 == ID_2)]
    elif not ID_1:
        new_df = df.loc[df.ID_2 == ID_2]
    elif not ID_2:
        new_df = df.loc[df.ID_1 == ID_1]    

    return new_df
```

Comment: Thank you but, as I've written in my original message, I can't use that method due to the high number of combinations in my real dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, `return_a_new_filtered_df` you are taking in two parameters and you have assigned default values to those parameters as (not None)

(not None) will be computed as True, hence both parameters will have default value True.

In the function call, `return_a_new_filtered_df(12,14)` everything will work as expected as the values passed `12` and `14` will override the default value `True` and `new_df = df.loc[(df.ID_1 == ID_1) & (df.ID_2 == ID_2)]` will be computed as expected.

But in the next call, `return_a_new_filtered_df(12)` the value of `ID_2` will remain as `True` and when doing `new_df = df.loc[(df.ID_1 == ID_1) & (df.ID_2 == ID_2)]` you wont get any match. Hence an empty dataframe is returned.

If you want to return a dataframe for ID_1 only then you can do something like this in your function.

```
def return_a_new_filtered_df(ID_1=None,ID_2=None):

     """
         return a new filtered dataframe

        Parameters:
        ID_1 (int): First ID
        ID_2 (int): Second ID

        Returns: a new pd dataframe

    """

    if ID_1 != None and ID_2 != None:
        new_df = df.loc[(df.ID_1 == ID_1) & (df.ID_2 == ID_2)]

    elif ID_2 == None:
        new_df = df.loc[(df.ID_1 == ID_1)]

    return new_df
```

Comment: Thank you for summarizing my problem but I understand perfectly why it returns an empty dataframe. My question is : what value can I set to make it return the entire dataframe?

Comment: You can't set any value. Maybe you can check the arguments and see how to split.

Comment: I could but, as I wrote in my original message, my real dataframe is a lot bigger and messier than that one and I have tons of IDs to filter (or not) and the code would be very sloppy...

Comment: So you want to filter more than 2 ids from the dataframe.? Is it like you have a list of IDs and select only data for those IDs.?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about!

Comment: So have you explored `isin` in pandas.?